# What does this React code with an anonymous closure do for validateFormat?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking at the source for `React 16.4.2` and noticed something that is a bit unfamiliar to me and was wondering how it works.  Here is the code:

```
var validateFormat = function validateFormat(format) {};

{
  validateFormat = function validateFormat(format) {
    if (format === undefined) {
      throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
    }
  };
}
```

As you can see, there is a variable being declared called `validaeFormat` and it is being assigned a function as its' value.  That makes sense to me.  However, immediately after this line you can see that the variable is being reassigned to a function with the same name but different logic within its closure.

The part that confuses me is the additional un-named closure around the re-assignment.  It seems to be a common paradigm in the source code for React.

**What is the purpose of the extra braces? How does that behave in run-time?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are looking at the [development version](https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.2/umd/react.development.js) of the React build.

The source is here: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/aeda7b745d9c080150704feb20ea576238a1b9a1/packages/shared/invariant.js

The code you found actually looks like this before *react.development.js* is transpiled. If you're not familiar with transpilation, have a quick [read about it here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them) but it's typically done in order to use language features that might not yet be supported in older browsers (like `let` and the arrow-function syntax).

```
let validateFormat = () => {};

if (__DEV__) {
  validateFormat = function(format) {
    if (format === undefined) {
      throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
    }
  };
}

export default function invariant(condition, format, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
  validateFormat(format);

  if (!condition) {
    let error;
    if (format === undefined) {
      error = new Error(
        'Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment ' +
          'for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.',
      );
    } else {
      const args = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
      let argIndex = 0;
      error = new Error(
        format.replace(/%s/g, function() {
          return args[argIndex++];
        }),
      );
      error.name = 'Invariant Violation';
    }

    error.framesToPop = 1; // we don't care about invariant's own frame
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Notice the `if (__DEV__)` bit? `__DEV__` is a global that is typically set to `true` or `false` depending on what kind of build they're running, so in the development build this code is going to look like

```
let validateFormat = () => {};

if (true) {
  validateFormat = function(format) {
    if (format === undefined) {
      throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
    }
  };
}
```

Now, when that build is optimised, the optimizer will detect that this `if` check is completely superfluous as it always evaluates to true so it just removes it. It's anyone's guess why it decided to keep the `{ }` block but it could be in order to not accidentally introduce scoping errors.

Now take a look at the [production version](https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js) of the React build. It would be generated with the `__DEV__` flag set to `false` and the optimizer would then realise that it can delete the entire if-clause. The result is that the `validateFormat` function is a no-op in production while it is doing checks in development. There's lots of these development checks in React that is removed in the production build to save Bytes.

Here's a somewhat prettified version of the code from that `variant.js` file in the production version of React.

```
O = function(a, b, f, d, c, k, h, g) {
    if (!a) {
        if (void 0 === b) a = Error("Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.");
        else {
            var e = [f, d, c, k, h, g],
                l = 0;
            a = Error(b.replace(/%s/g, function() {
                return e[l++]
            }));
            a.name = "Invariant Violation"
        }
        a.framesToPop = 1;
        throw a;
    }
},
```

The `if(!a)` check if actually the `if (!condition)` check from the original source code (the variable names have been minified to save even more Bytes). The call to `validateFormat()` that you can see in the source is gone since the entire function is just a no-op because it was never reassigned in the now removed `if (__DEV__)` block.

This strategy allows React to print helpful error messages and warnings when running in development mode while skipping them in production mode to save on network traffic and because the errors/warnings are of no value to the users.

So, that's it really. I hope that clarifies things a bit and that I didn't confuse you even further. What you found was basically just leftovers from a minification process that ran during the build-step.

Comment: wow, that was a really good explanation.  Thanks for taking the time to explain that!